# Load testing on CI/CD Teamcity with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, build-verification-test, team-city, build

I want to add Jmeter tests as build steps in TeamCity server. If tests fail, a build will not complete. Please share how to do it.

I am currently using Jmeter for testing a Rest API running different scenarios/threads on a standalone machine. My intention is to put these tests in our existing CI/CD that has TeamCity. When we deploy a new release, Jmeter tests will run as automation tests and if any test fails, then the build will roll back and generate failure reports.

Comment: WHat have you tried? What problems are you experiencing?

Comment: I am currently using Jmeter for a Rest API running different scenarios/threads. My intention is to put these tests in our existing CI/CD that has TeamCity. When we deploy a new release, jmeter tests will run and if any test fails, then the build will roll back and generate failure reports

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be returning a non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) in case if there are failures in JMeter tests.

It can be achieved by running your JMeter tests via [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which provides possibility to add [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) and in case if the criteria are not met, the test execution will fail and TeamCity capture the script return code and correspondingly fail the build.

References:

- [Taurus - JMeter Executor - Run Existing JMX File](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)